# Сделать клик мышью по заданным координатам

Tags: c#

нужно с определенной периодичностью жать на кнопку левой кнопкой мыши.

Нашел код:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll",
        CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention =
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags,
        int dx,
        int dy,
        int dwData,
        int dwExtraInfo);

    //Нормированные абсолютные координаты
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

    //Нажатие на левую кнопку мыши
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;

    //Поднятие левой кнопки мыши
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    //перемещение указателя мыши
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
static void Main()
    {
   //Координаты на экране:     
        int X = 1230;
        int Y = 1230;
        //Перемещение курсора на указанные координаты
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,
            System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,
            System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height, X, Y);

        //Выполнение первого клика левой клавишей мыши
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);

        //Выполнение второго клика левой клавишей мыши
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}
```

Но программа кликает мышью всегда в правом верхнем углу экрана независимо от того какие X и Y мы выбираем. В чем проблема?

Comment: В [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) сказано: Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В найденном вами коде содержится ошибка.

Неверно:

> // Перемещение курсора на указанные координаты
>      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,
>         System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,
>         System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height, X, Y);

Исправте на:

`mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, X, Y, 0, 0);`

где X и Y имеют значения между 0 и 65535.

Например, если мы хотим попасть в центр экрана:

`mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 32500, 32500, 0, 0);`